# Can't start mirth connect on windows server public IP

Tags: mirth-connect

Can't start mirth connect on windows server public IP. It is running fine on local IP. I have added the application in windows firewall exception list. Disabled the firewall but nothing worked.

Tried adding record in hosts file as well. But the web service is not accessible using public IP not even in the VM itself.

Comment: Does `mirth.log` have any error or warning messages?

Comment: @Freiheit Please ignore. It was Azure firewall issue.